# How to stop github pages from parsing YAML

Tags: github-pages

I've write a pure static blog **without jekyll engine**, it is **pure js static blog**.

I want to push my js blog to github pages, unfortunately it will parse YAML and get such an error:

> Your site is having problems building: **There was a YAML syntax error on line 3 column 14 in : mapping values are not allowed in this context**. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-invalid-yaml-in-data-file.

How to stop github pages from parsing YAML?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP should ask the GitHub support team instead. Note the "Contact a human" button at the end of the linked help page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable jekyll, add an empty file *.nojekyll* at the root of github page repo.

```
touch .nojekyll
git add .
git push
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by trial-and-error. If you put a YML comment as the first few lines, Jekyll will not process it.

```
# 
# Comment
# 

---
- hosts: all
```

In my case, I was trying to serve static .yml ansible playbooks and Jekyll kept parsing `"{{ item.name }}"` into `""` when the files were downloaded.