# How to serve YAML files with Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a YAML file that holds some data and needs to be processed client side.

```
---

some: content

...
```

Jekyll handles everything with Front Matter, which results in the whole YAML content to be treated as Front Matter and the page then has no content.

**Is there a way to tell Jekyll to treat the file as static, even though it has a YAML header?**

I tried different combinations of `exclude` and `keep_files`, also setting Front Matter defaults in my `_config.yml`, but nothing is really working.

My workaround now is to add an additional Front Matter block in front of the content:

```
---
layout: null
---
---

some: content

...
```

The YAML file though is a swagger definition and adding this extra block would both:

- make it complicated to test/generate the definition locally or in Swagger Editor
- Generate confusion, if the file is downloaded via github.

So ideally I would like to store the file without any modification and somehow teach Jekyll to leave it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to tell Jekyll to avoid to process a file with front matter without a plugin.

A simple solution would be to use Jekyll [hook's](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#hooks) to copy the original unprocessed file with front matter to the generated site just after the whole site has been generated.

For example, adding `_plugins/copyfile.rb`:

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :post_write do |site|
  src = "_unprocessed/about.md"
  dest = "_site/assets"
  puts "Copying #{src} to #{dest}"
  FileUtils.cp(src, dest)
end
```

That would copy `_unprocessed/about.md` **with front matter** to the final site `assets` dir.

As `_unprocessed` starts with an underscore it won't be present in the resulting site.

Building the site:

```
/tmp/s⟫jekyll b
Configuration file: /tmp/s/_config.yml
            Source: /tmp/s
       Destination: /tmp/s/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
Copying _unprocessed/about.md to _site/assets
                    done in 0.884 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.


/tmp/s⟫ tree _site/
_site/
├── 404.html
├── assets
│   ├── about.md
│   └── main.css
├── feed.xml
├── index.html
└── jekyll
    └── update
        └── 2017
            └── 11
                └── 09
                    └── welcome-to-jekyll.html

6 directories, 6 files
```

Answer (score 1):

Cross-posting my answer here as it may be relevant (not sure; I'm not a Jekyll user but github pages uses it.) https://stackoverflow.com/a/48954668/1461007